# Access OSX file system from iOS?

Tags: ios

I think it's unlikely, but does anyone know a way to access the OSX file system from an iOS app, connected by USB? Specifically I'd like to access iTunes backup files from iOS.

Answer (score -1):

An iOS app is sandboxed. It can't see outside the sandbox. And it is either running on a device or on the simulator, and either way it is unaware that your OS X computer even exists.

Comment: It is possible for the devices to communicate voluntarily; they don't always have to be "unaware" of each other. That's what Bonjour is for, for instance. As such, while OP's question is certainly too broad and spans [osx] and not just [ios], I think this answer is too narrow.

Comment: Well @jtbandes, he didn't ask how the iOS device and the computer could communicate; he asked how the iOS app could "access the OS X file system". I think my answer covers exactly that, and correctly.